# Merge "windows-firewall" with "windows-firewall-api"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

The tags seem to overlap a bit.

Should [windows-firewall](/questions/tagged/windows-firewall) be retagged or merged with [windows-firewall-api](/questions/tagged/windows-firewall-api)?

Answer (score 1):

There are questions, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480178/firewall-stopping-windows-service-to-run-smoothly, [Does my program need to have an exception in Windows firewall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531703/does-my-program-need-to-have-an-exception-in-windows-firewall) or [HttpListener: firewall says no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424838/httplistener-firewall-says-no), where [windows-firewall](/questions/tagged/windows-firewall) is being used, but the question is not about the Windows Firewall API. This means one of the following things:

- the two tags are not synonyms
- [windows-firewall](/questions/tagged/windows-firewall) should be removed from those questions where the Windows firewall is only marginally referred in the question

If they are synonym, [windows-firewall](/questions/tagged/windows-firewall) should be removed from those "I have troubles with Windows Firewall" questions, or those questions should be closed if they aren't on-topic for Stack Overflow; if [windows-firewall](/questions/tagged/windows-firewall) is acceptable in those "Windows Firewall is causing me issues with the application I am developing" questions, then the tags are not synonyms. In the latter case, the questions should be manually retagged to use [windows-firewall-api](/questions/tagged/windows-firewall-api).

Comment: Looks to me like the question you cited is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you're simply having trouble making an app work with the Windows Firewall, you need to ask on Super User. The only things that fit on Stack Overflow are questions about how to interact with the Windows Firewall *programmatically*, such as creating exceptions, etc. You'd do that using the API.